# Spring Roo Petclinic menu.jspx and Controller. How does it work?

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, spring-roo

FYI. I did post this on the Spring Roo forum but no reply.

This is a very basic question from a newbie.

The question is concerning how the Controller knows to direct the menu link , such as the following from the petclinic example

```
<menu:item id="i_pet_new" messageCode="global_menu_new" url="/pets?form" z="SwmuMoL7UBbDU/gqHy+t5Tl0Ins="/>
```

My current understanding is that the

```
@RequestMapping("/pets")

@Controller

 public class PetController {

}
```

Handles the url="/pet" portion but

**How does the Controller know how to handle the remaining portion? The portion that says "?form" ?**

I have done simple mvc projects before and I would have some code inside of the class PetController that would do something like:

```
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")

public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    mav.setViewName("helloWorld");

    mav.addObject("message", "Hello World!");

    return mav;

}
```

In the current example there are no additional methods to handle the ModelAndView !

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will notice the file `PetController_Roo_Controller.aj` created in the same folder as `PetController.java`.  This contains the relevant code to handle this.  Specifically,

```
@RequestMapping(params = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String PetController.createForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("pet", new Pet());
        return "pets/create";
    }
```

Roo takes care of the CRUD operations for you.